# Passing memory address as a file in c

Tags: c

If I have some sort of library that has a function like so `void foo(FILE* fp)`, and I have a `char*` array of data, is there any way for me to pass a pointer to the array or something similar to the `foo` function?.

What I'm doing now is using `system()` to write to a temporary file, and I don't really like doing that.

Comment: Is this in a POSIX environment? If so, you could use threads: One thread writes the array to the pipe, the other thread uses `fdopen()` to connect a `FILE*` to the read end of the pipe.

Comment: Yes, that's a great idea.

Answer (score 3):

No, the stdio library has no facility for defining your own buffering scheme.

Given POSIX and virtual memory, you can use `mmap` to open a memory region with a backing file. The OS may opt not to write the file to disk. Details vary by OS, but this can approach the ideal solution.

Or, as Barmar suggests, use `pipe` to send the data to the main thread from an auxiliary thread within your process.

As for the simple solution… why use `system()` when you can use `mktemp()`, `fopen()`, `fwrite()`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want [fmemopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmemopen.html).  Assuming you're running on Linux (or something else posixy; if you need Windows support, will have to check), it should be available.